# How to get the mode of a user-inputted list?

Tags: python

For a school python assignment, I need to take a user-inputted list of numbers and calculate the mode of the numbers. I have a main function that asks for the list and then separates that list into a mutable list, then puts them into order from least to greatest. However, my mode function doesn't seem to be working properly. When I run it, it delivers several results, only some of which are correct. Did I miss something in my code that is causing it to return too many

```css
def CalculateMode(numbers):
    dictionary = {}
    for num in numbers:
        number = dictionary.get(num, None)
        if number == None:
            dictionary[num] = 1
        else:
            dictionary[num] = number + 1
    maximum = max(dictionary.values())
    for key in dictionary:
        if dictionary[key] == 1:
            print("There is no mode.")
        if dictionary[key] == maximum:
            print("The mode is " + num + ".")
```

When I run the program and attempt to determine the mode with a list like 1, 2, 2, 3 (in which the mode should be 2), this is the result I get:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxhpD.png)

It outputs the incorrect mode as well as several messages saying there is no mode. Please let me know how to fix it!

Comment: You can use [`statistics.mode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mode).

Comment: I'm not supposed to import from other functions, I'm supposed to write my own def function as part of the chapter, since this chapter is about writing functions.

Comment: Please see the posting guidelines and provide a [minimal, reproducible example]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Off-site links and images are not acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

You only want to print once when looking for the mode:

```
for key in dictionary:
    if dictionary[key] == 1:
        print("There is no mode.")    # This will print for every key with count of 1
    if dictionary[key] == maximum:
        print("The mode is " + num + ".") # This will print for every key with count of "maximum"
```

You could do:

```
for key in dictionary:
    if dictionary[key] == maximum:
        print("The mode is " + num + ".")
        break # A for/else that breaks won't run else
else:
        print("There is no mode.") # prints if never hit break
```

But consider what if there are two maximums, like `[1,2,2,3,3,4]` or if maximum is 1 and "there is no mode"...[1,2,3,4,5]...that will still print the first value with count 1 and break.  So the logic is a bit flawed.  What does your assignment say the mode should be when more than one maximum exists?  Or should it print all the maximum values:

```
for key in dictionary:
    if dictionary[key] == maximum:
        print("A mode is " + num + ".")
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! This helped fix my problem with returning the incorrect mode, however the program still accounts for every number before it hits the mode and prints that there is no mode before printing the actual mode. It also does not account for multiple modes which I haven't quite figured out yet.

Comment: If the list has no mode [1,2,3,4,5], it should say that there is no mode. If the list has two modes [1,2,2,3,3,4], it should print both modes.